# Style issue with a button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have buttons which have a certain stylesheet. I took it from bootstrap. Now, I am dynamically creating another button and want the same features as the above mentioned button. How can I do it?. 
element.style="" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply them the same class:

```
element.className = 'btn';
```